# Understanding recursion better in linked lists

Tags: list, recursion, linked-list, pascal

I would like to understand recursion on a deeper level and not just intuitively. I know the concept and I know how to solve a factorial or a fibonacci sequence recursively. But I don't seem to be able to visualize very well what exactly happens in a linked list when used recursively.

More specifically I am struggling to understand the following algorithm:

(It looks for the maximum in a linked list. It does so by recursively searching for the maximum starting from the second element. Then it compares it with the first element and returns the higher one.)

```
 function MaxRec (inRefBegin : tRefList) : tRefList;
  { returns recursively a pointer to the max element in a list }

    var
    rekMax : tRefList; { variable to point to the recursive maximum 
                          starting from second element }
    begin
      if inRefBegin = nil then { Base Case, recursion stops }
        MaxRec := nil
      else
      begin
        rekMax := MaxRec (inRefBegin^.next); 
        if rekMax = nil then
          MaxRec := inRefBegin
        else
          if inRefBegin^.info < rekMax^.info then
            MaxRec := rekMax
          else
            MaxRec := inRefBegin
      end { if }
    end; { MaxRec }
```

I do understand what in theory should happen. I have trouble visualizing it step by step. What happens at every stack level?
What I don't get is how does this line: `rekMax := MaxRec (inRefBegin^.next)` can find the maximum.... it only calls the function with a pointer to the next item but is not comparing any values.... Or do I compare each time the function is called??

My thought process is like this: 
Let's say I have a linked list like this:

```
5 => 7 => 10 => 3 => 2 => nil
```

1. Function is called and is not nil ((saved to stack))
2. Function is called and is not nil ((saved to stack))
3. Function is called and is not nil ((saved to stack))
4. Function is called and is not nil ((saved to stack))
5. Function is called and is not nil ((saved to stack))
6. Recursion stops
7. Now what happens? Do I compare in each function with the first element? Or is this the point where I already have my recursive max? Can s.o visualize this?

I am very grateful for every help. I know this topic has heaps of sources online and believe me I have read them. But it is still not clear to me what exactly is going on on every level.

Comment: Um, this function that you show isn't recursive at all, as far as I can see. Add the code for `ZeigListMax`  to the question, it may be.

Comment: sorry mate, my bad, I updated the code. Now it should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > 7) Now what happens? Do I compare in each function with the first element? Or is this the point where I already have my recursive max? Can s.o visualize this?

At 7) recursion stops because you've reached the end of the list, so nil is returned.
You then continue in the previous call where the result from MaxRec is now nil, so the max for that last part is the current inRefBegin value (again, since nil was returned).

For the other levels, going out of the recursion, the value in the current node is compared to what was returned from the recursive call, and the greatest one is retained, until, finally, you are left with the greatest node for the entire list.

Does that help?

Comment: thank you my friend for the explanation.... I don't know if I get it 100%.... you say " the max for that last part is the current inRefBegin value"... What is the current inRefBegin value? Also you say " the value in the current node is compared to what was returned from the recursive call, and the greatest one is retained", but which line of code does that exactly?

Comment: The current inRetBegin value is each entry in the list, in turn, as the recursion walks the list. As to `which line does` the comparison, there's only one line with a compare, and based on the result of that either the current node value or what was returned from the recursive call is chosen as the new, local max.

Comment: Ok, thanks ver y much again. Let me try and go through that starting from 7 with that list:

1. Recursion stops and nil is returned
2. That's why rekMax now points to nil
3. inRefBegin points to 2 and rekMax points to nil. That's why 2 is returned
4. inRefBegin points to 3 and rekMax points to 2. That's why 3 is returned
5. inRefBegin points to 10 and rekMax points to 3. That's why 10 is returned
6. inRefBegin points to 7 and rekMax points to 10. That's why 10 is returned
7. inRefBegin points to 5 and rekMax points to 10. That's why 10 is returned.

Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, you got it :)

Comment: oh man, that's fantastic! Thank you so much my friend, I've spend days trying to wrap my head around this!